# Android: Move View after animation?

Tags: android, animation

I'm trying to basically have a button move down to the bottom of the screen with an animation after it is clicked.

I have the animation working perfectly, but the button doesn't stay at the bottom of the screen after the animation finishes. I've tried using `offsetTopAndBottom()`, but it only stays down there for one frame, and is redrawn at the top. How can I get the button to stay?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you try to call `setFillAfter(true)` on your animation instance?

Regards!

Comment: Adding that didn't work. It seems like this should be an easy problem to fix, I can't imagine how anyone could do any animation without solving this problem.

Comment: ... and did you call setFillEnabled(true) before setFillAfter(true)?

Comment: Haha, it actually did work, I was calling it on the wrong object though. :P 

Anyways, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `setFillAfter(true)` works.

But the strange thing is that corresponding `android:fillAfter` XML attribute does not provide same effect. Be aware, guys.

Answer (score 0):

Your button is not clickable because you are using **View** animation instead of the **Property** Animation.
View animation only change where your View is drawn instead of really moving it to that location.
Property animation does the trick.

I answered your question on another thread.
You can check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333269/how-to-set-button-clickable-while-animating-on-android/18509197#18509197).