# Android WindowManager position like Facebook Reactions Behavior

Tags: android, android-animation, android-windowmanager

this is a sequence of this  [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36734610/similar-facebook-reactions-animated-view-with-objectanimator-clicklistener-not)

I'm trying to replicate the implementation of Facebook Reactions but Vertically, someone answered that was made with WindowManager.
I've created a layout with buttons,
set setOnTouchListener to take MotionEvent.ACTION_DONW, when rvIv1 is pressed on the Cardview I catch catch event.getRawX and event.getRawY,this is the code i have.

```
    vHolder.rvIv1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int eveX =(int) event.getRawX();
            int eveY =(int) event.getRawY();

            int measureHeight = (vHolder.ivHappy.getMeasuredHeight());

            if(vHolder.mViewExpressions == null)
                vHolder.mViewExpressions = new ExpressionsView(activity);

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                Log.d("Pressed", "Button pressed");
               /// createFloatView();
                

                if(vHolder.mViewExpressions.getWindowToken() == null){
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            eveX, eveY,
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                            0 | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
                  //  params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.LEFT;

                  /*  params.x = eveX;
                      params.y = eveY;
                    */
                    wm.addView(vHolder.mViewExpressions, params);

                    vHolder.isClosed = false;
                }else{

                }
            }
            else{
             //     WindowManager.removeView(vHolder.mViewExpressions);
                if(vHolder.mViewExpressions != null && vHolder.mViewExpressions.getWindowToken() != null){
                    wm.removeView(vHolder.mViewExpressions);
                    vHolder.isClosed = true;
                }
                Log.d("Released", "Button released");
            }


            return true;
        }


    });
```

- I tried positioning with v.getX() and Y;, event.getRawX and Y without luck.
- I have objectanimations in the ViewExpressions but never fired.
- How can i pass touchlistener to my ViewExpressions because when I try to slide my finger the window closes because get in else .

[image]

Please I apreciate your help.
Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: are you trying to make the RecyclerView scrollable when the ViewExpressions pop out?and ViewExpressions will scroll following the RecyclerView?if this is the case, it will be a little more complicated

Comment: Well i think when popup is launched disable scroll while user is touching, also it's one of the goal I want to get but it dosn't work, i tried recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);. like facebook reactions works :-(