# Why i can't click my button while its animated?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-animation

i have a imageButton with a animation(moving from point A to B), and i want to make him invisible if I click it, the problem is, the button doesn't become invisible while the animation is on.

Animation code:

```
Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0,-500, 600); 
animation.setDuration(6000); 
animation.setFillAfter(true); 
rndCoin.startAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: Please show some code, so we can help you better

Comment: Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0,-500, 600);
    animation.setDuration(6000);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    rndCoin.startAnimation(animation);

thats the animation code

Comment: Mário, don't put your code in coments. Edit your question to explain better what is your problem. This code should be inside your question

Comment: Anyway, How are you trying to make it invisible?

Comment: posso falar em portugues? es pt certo?

Comment: Although Portuguese is my main language, no, you can't write in Portuguese... Sorry, but this site in meant for english... If you would like to ask a question in Portuguese, you can use this site: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/. But don't worry! There are many developers that are going to correct your english if it's bad... Just edit your question (put the code inside the question) and I will do my best to help you!

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, i found how to solve my problem anyway. Thanks :)

Comment: Just use Property Animation and you will be fine haha. You are welcome man, just remember to edit your questions properly to avoid get down voted.

Answer (score 2):

You problem is that you are using View animation, and it makes you button unclickable until your animation ends.

There are two types of animation:

**View animation:** It's a more simple and easier to use, but you have some limitation (like the one you have right now!) - You can check more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html)

**Property Animation:** It is a more robust framework. You don't necessarily have to use this with Views, you can animate pretty much anything... Just use your creativity. With this kind of animation you will be able to change the visibility of your button while the animation is going on. Take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) for more info.

Source: [Android Animation - Button stays clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333269/android-animation-button-stays-clickable)